# Image differencing: How to find minor differences between images?

Tags: c++, image, edge-detection, threshold

i want to find hwo to get diff b/w 2 similar grayscale images for implementation in system for security purposes. I want to check whether any difference has occurred between them. For object tracking, i have implementd canny detection in the program below. I get outline of structured objects easily.. which cn later be subtracted to give only the outline of the difference in the delta image....but what if there's a non structural difference such as smoke or fire in the second image? i have increased the contrast for clearer edge detection as well have modified threshold vals in the canny fn parameters..yet got no suitable results.

also canny edge detects shadows edges too. if my two similar image were taken at different times during the day, the shadows will vary, so the edges will vary and will give undesirable false alarm

how should i work around this? Can anyone help? thanks!
Using c language api in `enter code here`opencv 2.4 in visual studio 2010

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
IplImage* img1 = NULL;
        if ((img1 = cvLoadImage("libertyH1.jpg"))== 0)
        {
                printf("cvLoadImage failed\n");
        }
     IplImage* gray1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); //contains greyscale      //image
        CvMemStorage* storage1 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);         //struct for storage
        cvCvtColor(img1, gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);               //convert to greyscale
    cvSmooth(gray1, gray1, CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7);              // This is done so as to //prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
    IplImage* canny1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
        IplImage* rgbcanny1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray1),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
        cvCanny(gray1, canny1, 50, 100, 3);                 //cvCanny( const //CvArr* image, CvArr* edges(output edge map), double threshold1, double threshold2, int //aperture_size CV_DEFAULT(3) );

    cvNamedWindow("Canny before hough");
    cvShowImage("Canny before hough", canny1);
        CvSeq* circles1 = cvHoughCircles(gray1, storage1, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray1->height/3,    250, 100);
        cvCvtColor(canny1, rgbcanny1, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    cvNamedWindow("Canny after hough");
        cvShowImage("Canny after hough", rgbcanny1);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < circles1->total; i++)
        {
                // round the floats to an int
                float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles1, i);
                cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
                 int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
// draw the circle center
                cvCircle(rgbcanny1, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
 // draw the circle outline
                cvCircle(rgbcanny1, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

                printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
        }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    IplImage* img2 = NULL;
    if ((img2 = cvLoadImage("liberty_wth_obj.jpg"))== 0)
   {
printf("cvLoadImage failed\n");
    }
    IplImage* gray2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    cvCvtColor(img2, gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // This is done so as to prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
    cvSmooth(gray2, gray2, CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7);
    IplImage* canny2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img2),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    IplImage* rgbcanny2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img2),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    cvCanny(gray2, canny2, 50, 100, 3);
    CvSeq* circles2 = cvHoughCircles(gray2, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray2->height/3, 250, 100);
    cvCvtColor(canny2, rgbcanny2, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles2->total; i++)
    {
 // round the floats to an int
             float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles2, i);
            cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
            int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
// draw the circle center
        cvCircle(rgbcanny2, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
              // draw the circle outline
             cvCircle(rgbcanny2, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );
             printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to add the code. **Edit** the question to add the code

Answer (score 1):

You want code help here? This is not an easy task. There are few algorithms available in internet or you can try to invent new one. A lot of research is going on this. I have some idea about a process. You can find the edges by `Y` from `YCbCr` color system. Deduct this `Y` value from blurred image's `Y` value. Then you will get the edge. Now make an array representation. You have to divide the image in blocks. Now check the block with blocks. It may slide, rotated, twisted etc. Compare with array matching. Object tracking is difficult due to background. Take care/omit unnecessary objects carefully.

Comment: code help or algorithm, anything..and will this method apply on greyscale images too, @pcbabu?

Comment: Gray scale image already gives the image intensity (Y part). So, it will help too. If you can implement or find any new algorithm. I also need it :)

Comment: Is image registration viable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go could be Background subtraction. It lets you cope with lighting conditions changes.

See [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_subtraction) for an intro. The basic idea is you have to build a model for the scene background, then all differences are computed relative to the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some analysis on Image Differencing but the code was written for java. Kindly look into the below link that may come to help

[How to find rectangle of difference between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704716/how-to-find-rectangle-of-difference-between-two-images/20116720#20116720)

Cheers !